# Is there a way to observe the sum of a set of values from a Room Database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a set of reading logs in a Room database, and I want to be able to observe the SUM of the `minutesRead` column for all rows with today's date, to be able to know how many pages a user has read today.  I'm able to query for the sum, and get it properly using this method:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(pagesRead) FROM log_table WHERE bookId IS :bookId AND date >= :date")
fun getPagesRead(bookId: String, date: Long): Int?
```

My question is, is there a way to observe this somehow, so that any time a log is added that has today's date, it recalculates the sum and updates all its observables?

Answer (score -1):

you can use live data to observe changes.

change return type to `LiveData<Int>` :

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(pagesRead) FROM log_table WHERE bookId IS :bookId AND date >= :date")
fun getPagesRead(bookId: String, date: Long): LiveData<Int>
```

observe it like this :

```
getPagesRead.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { sum ->
            // Update the UI.
        })
```

LiveData dependency :

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
```

Comment: Is that guaranteed to fire every time a new log is added that meets the date criteria?  I thought I had tried returning a LiveData (like I do with most Room queries), but I don't remember it working

Comment: Yeah I just tried this again, and it does not trigger the LiveData that I have in the ViewModel

Comment: This works for if one of the entries included in the original query is modified.  In that case, the LiveData will update, but if a new entry is added that meets the criteria, it is not.

Comment: @cpgreen2 you can create function that gets pages and observe it as a list and then get the sum